# How to check (get) my current fragment index? Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back

I have 5 fragments, which I can swipe by pressing the button.

I want to go back for example from fragment 5 to fragment 1, from fragment 4 to fragment 3 etc. by pressing back button.

I write in onBackPressed() method:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.setCurrentItem(0, true);
}
```

So when I press back button, I will go to the first fragment. I have a question, how can I get current fragment? I want to check it in this method for example:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (FourthFragment) {
        this.setCurrentItem(2, true);
    } else if (FifthFragment) {
        this.setCurrentItem(0,true);
    }  etc...
}
```

Comment: Are you using `ViewPager` or using `FragmentTransaction` to replace the fragments?

Comment: ViewPager. I can insert my code later. Sorry, I cant now.

Comment: No problem, but you use the `ViewPager.getCurrentItem()` to discover the selected `Fragment` index. Take a look: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem().

Comment: Thank you! It's working :) Write it as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`ViewPager.getCurrentItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem%28%29) you can retrieve what is the index of current `Fragment` and use it on your navigation logic.

Answer (score 0):

with     `ViewPager.getCurrentItem()`    you will get wrong value index
right index is `Fragment.mIndex`
to get it, you can use:  `getTag()`
last value is mIndex